# Differences between 'up to now' and 'so far'

Tags: phrase-usage

Is there any Difference between 'up to now' and 'so far' except to the condition when 'So is' is used for 'distance' in the sentence ? I would be greatfull if anyone would tell me,thanks

Answer (score 3):

In most situations they are interchangeable. According to this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=well%20up%20to%20now%2C%20well%20up%20until%20now%2C%20well%20so%20far&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwell%20up%20to%20now%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwell%20up%20until%20now%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwell%20so%20far%3B%2Cc0), **so far** seems to be significantly more common than **up to now**.

In situations where something is coming to an end, there may be a preference for **up to now**, whereas **so far** implies that the situation will continue:

> Meals in the staff canteen have been subsidised **up to now**, but from January the subsidy will be withdrawn.
>
> The festival has been pretty good **so far**- let's hope it stays that way!

Comment: Are you not sure of your answer as you have used 'may' ?

Comment: I use 'may' because English is not always exact: usage varies between individual English speakers. YMMV.

Comment: Are you talking abt America or british English ?

Comment: British English. My own experience and this. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259169/up-to-now-vs-until-now

Comment: I agree with this as American English as well. I think "up to now" is really a spinoff of "up until now", implying the situation has ended. "Things were going great, up until now." "So far" suggests the current situation is ongoing. "Things are going great, so far."